# Ionic show blank content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webview

I works in an app thas has a large dynamic form thar show/hide questions according to the answers from this questions.
And some content show a blank html in diferents emulator or tablets but if I view the app in the chrome://inspect I view de HTML correctly.

This error does not occur on all emulators or devices, nor does it always occur on the same device (if it occurs on one device or emulator, it occurs more frequently). Is it a bug from ionic + webview from android? Maybe a misconfiguration of my project?

[image: This errors]

The package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.4",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ionic-selectable": "4.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.64",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Never hapenned to me, but, can you try to build your app without ionic ? Like just un "ng serve" ? (And see what happens)

Comment: hi @RicardoMachado, when starst with ng the app dont start because I uses variuos native plugins and the app dont render correctly in chrome o firefox